# How should we resolve SampleExtraction Error in LogQL? We want to find maximum value of field after grouping the data in LogQL

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-loki, logql

We already have info on the count of requests which has response time greater than 3000ms.
Now we have to find out the max response time from those requests.
Example:
`|**Request**| **Count**|`
`|Req1       |   5      |`
`|Req2       |   3      |`

So we want to know for Req1, out of 5 what is the max response time using LogQL?
We tried the below Query:

**max_over_time({application="xxx",namespace="xxx"} | json | message_app="xxxxx" | message_env="xxx" | unwrap message_duration | message_duration > 3000ms [48h])  by (message_path)**

But getting below error:
Query error
**pipeline error: 'SampleExtractionErr' for series: '{**error**="SampleExtractionErr", application="xxx", level="xxx", message_app="xxx", message_duration="6.882514ms", message_env="xx", message_path="/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/test1.html?RN=24.0.0_b0017", namespace="xxx", origin="xxxx"}'. Use a label filter to intentionally skip this error. (e.g | **error**!="SampleExtractionErr"). To skip all potential errors you can match empty errors.(e.g **error**="") The label filter can also be specified after unwrap. (e.g | unwrap latency | **error**="" )**